# Loop to Variable then print var

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a variable based on the `id` & `name` of fields with a specific `class`. But I'm having some trouble as my JS is a bit rusty thanks to years of jQuery.

Bellow Is my code and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jrvk3xhx/1/) is the js fiddle for it.

So first off I'm checking for a `click` then if the class `invalid` exists then run a loop to find the `name attribute` & `ID attribute` of each element that has the class `invalid`.

That then adds it to an `array` and I print the `array`.

Simple enough but it doesn't seem to be playing ball. I'm blaming years of using jQuery on this because I should be able to pop out something as simple as a loop in JS no problem. But I'm at a loss and can't seem to find an error as to why I don't get the print to the console log.

```js
document.getElementById("submiter").onclick = function() {
  errorLoop();
};

function errorLoop() {
    var errClass = element.classList.contains("invalid"),
      runner = document.document.getElementsByClassName("invalid"),
      dataL = [];


    if (errClass) {

      for (var i = 0; i < runner.length; i++) {
        var errName = runner.getAttribute("name"),
          errId = runner.getAttribute("id");

        dataL.push("Name: " + errName + " - ID: " + errId +", ");
      } //End for

      dataL.toString();

      console.debug(dataL);

      dataLayer.push({
        "validationError": "datal"
      });

    } //End if
  } //End errorLoop
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="tiMs" name="ti" value="Ms" tabindex="16" class="invalid">
<input type="radio" id="tiMiss" name="ti" value="Miss" tabindex="17" class="invalid">
<input type="radio" id="tiMiss" name="hol" value="Miss" tabindex="17" class="invalid">
<a href="#" id="submiter">
  <strong>clickit</strong>
</a>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on the Distribute line.

Comment: remove `+` sign from this line 
   `Distribute(dataL.push("Name: " + errName + " - ID: " + errId + )); ` 

i.e. make it to "` Distribute(dataL.push("Name: " + errName + " - ID: " + errId )); ` "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed code according to your requirement

```js
function foo() {
  errorLoop();
 }

 function errorLoop() {
  var runner = document.getElementsByClassName("invalid"), dataL = [];
  

  if (runner) {

   for (var i = 0; i < runner.length; i++) {
    var errName = runner[i].getAttribute("name"), errId = runner[i]
      .getAttribute("id");

    dataL.push("Name: " + errName + " - ID: " + errId);
   } //End for

   dataL.toString();
          console.log(dataL)

   console.debug(dataL);

   

  } //End if
 } //End errorLoop
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="tiMs" name="ti" value="Ms" tabindex="16"
  class="invalid">
 <input type="radio" id="tiMiss" name="ti" value="Miss" tabindex="17"
  class="invalid">
 <input type="radio" id="tiMiss" name="hol" value="Miss" tabindex="17"
  class="invalid">
 <a href="#" id="submiter" onclick="foo()"> <strong>clickit</strong>
 </a>
```

Comment: On click function was there for a reason as it cannot be inside the html but thinks for looking it over

Comment: Do you need anything else @DCdaz. Or is this working fine for you

Comment: Can you explain what you changed and what the issue is? Just posting code is not very useful for other visitors.

Comment: I removed some code (variables,method calls) which was undefined in my js and changed logic in for loop

Comment: I for loop you have to loop through all elements so replaced runner.getAttribute("name") to runner[i].getAttribute("name")

Comment: Here runner is array of elements with invalid class

Answer (score 0):

You may try below changes:

```
function errorLoop() {
   var errClass = element.classList.contains("invalid"),
   runner = document.getElementsByClassName("invalid"), // removed document
   dataL = [];


if (errClass) {

  for (var i = 0; i < runner.length; i++) {
    var errName = runner[i].getAttribute("name"), //used index
      errId = runner[i].getAttribute("id");

    //....
  } //End for

}

  //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this will may help you

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var arrNumber = new Array();
 $('#submiter').on('click',function(){
  $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('class')=='invalid'){
      arrNumber.push($(this).attr('id')+' => '+$(this).attr('name'));
     }
   });
   console.log(arrNumber);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thats jQuery not Javascript